# Accessing Django request inside model manger

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that gets called in 300+ places inside my codebase, each model has to be filtered by the `company_filter` by default, no exceptions. I need values from the request namely `tenant_id` and `tenant_type`, these values are available on every request. I filter the `Company` model using the `tenant_id` and then pass the `company`, `tenant_id` and `tenant_type` to the filter which then filters the Queryset, this seems to work just fine but I'm not sure about memory leaks and requests maybe getting mixed up for different users? Is there a better approach to accomplish this or is this a valid approach?

#### Middleware

```
import threading

_thread_local = threading.local()


class RequestMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        _thread_local.request = request

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Free up the memory after view is returns
        del _thread_local.request

        return response


def get_request():
    return getattr(_thread_local, 'request', None)
```

#### Model

```
class TariffrateCompanyManger(models.Manager):
    # Filters the tariff by the company by default
    def get_queryset(self):
        from config.middleware import get_request

        request = get_request()

        company = Company.objects.get_company_tenant_id(request.tenant_id)

        company_filter = tariff_company_filter(company, request.tenant_id, request.tenant_type)

        if request:
            qs = super().get_queryset().filter(company_filter)
        else:
            qs = super().get_queryset()

        return qs
```

Answer (score 0):

How you can filter yours queryset on every request depends on your project.

At first, it is not good solution to work with locals. Have many issue, and not "safe", if you really want to use *"thread safe" locals*, use _active fom django. It is your `locals`, in better form:

```
from django.utils.trans.trans_real import _active


class RequestMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        _active.request = request

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Free up the memory after view is returns
        return response


def get_request():
    return getattr(_active, 'request', Request())
```

By the way, If you returns Default request instead of `None`, your code will works better, you returns only one type of data - "Request". And not two: "Request" and "None"

But once more time - it is a wrong approach, to filter BASE queryset, which should be the same for ALL requests.

### How I solve those issue:

At first some preparing:

Don't use manager, or define manager through TariffrateCompanyQueryset.
It help you to made queryset chaning.

```
class TarifRateCompanyQueryset(models.Queryset):

    def filter_by_company(self, request):
        company_filter = Q()
        if hasattr(request, 'tenant_id'):
            company_filter &= Q(tenant_type=request.tenant_type,                
                            company__tarif__tennant_id==request.tenant_id)

        return self.filter()
```

I don't work with database to create Filter, it give you -1 hit to database.
Dont forget to declare "`objects`" in right form:

```
class TarifRateCompany(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = TarifRateCompanyQueryset.as_manager()
    ...
```

After that, try to see, where you need filtered queryset:

Django.Admin:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return super().get_queryset(request).filter_by_company(request)
```

Django.ModelView:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().filter_by_company(self.request)
```

Django-RestFramework:

```
class FilterByCompanyBackend(BaseFilterBackend):
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter_by_company(request)
```

Django Forms:

```
MyFormCls = modelform_factory(Company, formfield_callback=lambda *args, **kwargs: MyFunc(request, *args, **kwargs))
```

where `MyFunc` get `request` and form `fields` and you can sort queryset of TarifRateCompany field, if you have it.
more here: [about modelformfactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/models/#modelform-factory)

And, of course, i use Mixin to change base queryset filter in many models. In my small project I filter queryset by request in 1261 places across 197 files. With MixIn i have only one place where i do it.